# Determine if Switch state was changed by user

Tags: android, android-fragments

Let's say I inflate several copies of a 'template' layout file that each contains a `Switch` and I set an OnCheckedChangeListener on each switch like so:

```
switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                        if (b) {
                            //Switch is "on"
                        } else {
                            //Switch is "off"
                        }
                    }
                });
```

First off, this is fine, except when I switch fragments, this listener gets called for every `Switch` in the layout and it counts the state as being whatever the state of the most recently inflated `Switch` is.

Example: 
I inflate 4 copies of the template and insert them into the layout as they are created. I then switch the most recently created `Switch` to "on". I then change fragments and the `OnCheckedChanged` listener is called for all 4 switches and the `boolean` determining if they are `checked` or not is `true` regardless of their actual state.

To fix this, I altered the listener to be as follows:

```
switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                        if (compoundButton.isPressed()) {
                            if (b) {
                                //Switch is "on"
                            } else {
                                //Switch is "off"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

While this doesn't stop the listeners from being called when switching fragments, it does prevent those listeners from doing anything, which is all well and good except when the user swipes very quickly in which case `isPressed()` returns `false` and the expected behaviour is not observed.

I'm having trouble determining if the user initiated the change or if it was initiated by some automatic process and I'm looking to either determine that or working out why they get called every time I change to a new fragment from one that contains Switches.

This behaviour is bizarre and I imagine it's a result of the way `Switch` is implemented.

Expected behaviour: When switching fragments, no OnCheckedChanged listeners are called.

Observed: All listeners are called when switching fragment.

Has anyone encountered this before and has any solutions or insights into what is going on here?

EDIT: Here is how the views are being inflated:

```
View template = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.template, null);
```

Then to get a reference to the switch:

```
final Switch switch = (Switch) template.findViewById(R.id.switch);
```

I have done stuff like this before and it has worked fine, can I not do this specifically with Switches or something similar?

I do not need to maintain their state between fragments, they cause a record to be updated in the database and this is a problem regardless of if the new fragment is related to the old one or not. I just need the listener to not be called if the user didn't touch or swipe the Switch.

Apologies for the lack of clarity.

Comment: Do you wish to hold the state of switch (checked/unchecked) in each fragment?

Comment: Not clear for me if you inflate the template from different fragments or not. If so, each fragment will be attached / detached to an activity once it's shown. Then you'll need to set the listener in onStart() and unset the listener in onStop() for instance, so that once the given fragment is detached it won't listen to the state anymore.
Also, make sure your switches have all differents ids in the xml layout(s), otherwise you're passing around always the same instance of a switch.

Comment: Updated my question with some more details.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so this turns out to have been caused by duplicate ID's.

Assigning a unique id to each view seems to have fixed it:

`switch.setId(View.generateViewId());`

Thanks to Alessio for giving me a hint with his comment.